# MVC4 Bundling Cache Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I want to change the cache headers sent from a bundle request. Currently it is varying by `User-Agent` but I don't want it to, is there a way to change the headers sent by a bundle request?

After a quick look in the `System.Web.Optimization` assembly I can see the headers get set in `Bundle.SetHeaders` which is a private static function so I don't think its possible although I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'd also be interested in any thoughts from anyone on the logic for adding this header in the first place - e.g. does the bundling code itself behave differently depending on the user agent? Or is it just a precaution?

Comment: In regards to why we do this, its needed for the VS Page Inspector feature which sends a custom user agent using IE, so to prevent IE's cache from messing up requests to either page inspector, or serving page inspector bundles to IE outside of VS.

Comment: @HaoKung I have the same problem, I want to be able to set the cache-control header value to `public,max-age=31536000` instead of `private`, and to also add an Etag header.  It looks like both of these are not currently possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't something that we currently expose today.  We only expose the Cacheability property on the BundleResponse that a IBundleTransform could change.  And yes we explicitly set the following things:

```
                HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = context.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cachePolicy.SetCacheability(bundleResponse.Cacheability);
                cachePolicy.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
                cachePolicy.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
                cachePolicy.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
                cachePolicy.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
                cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["User-Agent"] = true;
```

We have a work item our backlog to open this up and make this more extensible/customizable in the future.

Comment: is there any indication as to the timeline on this change, the impact of this header plays havoc with CDN integration

Comment: Issue tracker url: https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/136 .  Also mentions a possible workaround.

Comment: It's been almost six years.  Any progress on fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround around it as mentioned in [janv8000's comment on this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074223/4924629). You need to add the following URL rewrite rule to your web server:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Cache Bundles" preCondition="IsBundles" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Vary" pattern="User-Agent" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="Accept-Encoding" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsBundles" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="*/bundles/*" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Obviously you need to pay attention to have all your bundles in your bundles folder or change the `IsBundles` precondition accordingly.