# MVC bundle client caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, resourcebundle

By default a MVC bundle is cached on client for 1 year. Is it possible to set it's client headers manually (for 1 specific bundle)?

What I need is to set custom expire headers for one of my bundles. I can't rely on the "v=hash" querystring because this bundle is for an external website, and they won't change the url pointing to my bundle each time I change it.

What I've tried is to create a custom Bundle class (inherit Bundle) and overridde the GenerateBundleResponse() method. This way I can control the server caching, but the only way of customizing client caching is to set BundleResponse.Cacheability (public, private, nocache etc). But I can't set headers manually. I have access to the BundleContext (and it's HttpContext), but when I set headers on that context, it will have effect for all other requests as well.

Comment: Sounds like you need VaryByXXX, but it looks like that flexibility is not there yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065330/mvc4-bundling-cache-headers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way. You can find the reason in the internal implementation of bundling. in the `BundleHandler` class ProcessRequest calls the `ProcessRequest`, internal method of the `Bundle` class and it calls SetHeaders just before the `HttpContext.Response.Write`. Therefore the client cache is set to one year just before the response write.

Note: `BundleHandler` is a internal sealed class:  `internal sealed class BundleHandler : IHttpHandler`

In the `BundleHandler` class:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    context.Response.Clear();
    BundleContext context2 = new BundleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), BundleTable.Bundles, this.BundleVirtualPath);
    if (!Bundle.GetInstrumentationMode(context2.HttpContext) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"]))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 304;
    }
    else
    {
        this.RequestBundle.ProcessRequest(context2);
    }
}
```

In the `Bundle` class:

```
internal void ProcessRequest(BundleContext context)
{
    context.EnableInstrumentation = GetInstrumentationMode(context.HttpContext);
    BundleResponse bundleResponse = this.GetBundleResponse(context);
    SetHeaders(bundleResponse, context);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write(bundleResponse.Content);
}

private static void SetHeaders(BundleResponse bundle, BundleContext context)
{
    if (bundle.ContentType != null)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = bundle.ContentType;
    }
    if (!context.EnableInstrumentation)
    {
        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = context.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetCacheability(bundle.Cacheability);
        cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
        cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
        cache.VaryByHeaders["User-Agent"] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: see stackoverflow.com/a/34508048/1545567 to workaround that and fully control the cache duration

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of the ASP.NET MVC bundling feature is that if any of the files that compose a bundle change - the query string for that bundle will automatically change - assuming you are using the following in your view's code:

```
@Scripts.Render("bundle name")
```

So this means if you have a new version of a file that is in a bundle, the next time your page renders a view that uses that bundle, it will send a script tag that the client browser will not found in its cache (since the query string is different).

So it seems like this will solve your problem - depends on what you mean by:

> and they won't change the url pointing to my bundle each time I change
>   it

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I try to explain I can't rely on the "v=hash" querystring because this bundle is for an external website.

Comment: I think I understand --- you should edit your question to be a little clearer - that you want an external website's page to include <script src="/yoursite/bundlename?v=xxxxxxxx"></script>

Comment: @stian.net: Just add ticks to the query string of the bundle, whatever the version is. That will invalidate client caching.

Answer (score 3):

What seems to work for me is giving the bundle a version number in the bundle config, then reference the new version in your markup.

Comment: @cdomination Why though? If this is a viable solution, what's wrong with posting it as such?

Comment: @cdomination only smart users can post in comments section, as at least 50 points needed otherwise you can only answer a question

Answer (score 2):

While there is not a better way to setup bundles cacheability, you can create a HttpModule which identifies the requests to the bundle and set the content cacheability.

You have the same effect doing this on the Global.asax:

```
    public override void Init()
    {
        this.EndRequest += MvcApplication_EndRequest;
        base.Init();
    }

    void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = this.Request;
        var response = this.Response;

        if (request.RawUrl.Contains("Content/"))
        {
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of Adilson's answer, but without having to create an HttpModule:

In the global.asax.cs of the MVC project:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("/bundles/")) {
        // My bundles all have a /bundles/ prefix in the URL
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an extra query string parameter to the url and change it everey time you want the cache to refresh.

e.g: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EwJeVbHWLcX08wfgwoCoBA&gws_rd=ssl&custom=abc

the last parameter is custom.