# How can we enable caching for Bundles in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have created 2 bundles in my mvc project as given below:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/BaseScripts").Include(
            "~/Content/js/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Content/js/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
            "~/Content/js/bootstrap.js",
             "~/Content/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
              "~/Scripts/customvalidation.js"

            )
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/CustomScripts").Include(
                        "~/Content/js/customscripts/commonscript.js",
          "~/Content/js/customscripts/registration.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Styles/Css").Include(
            "~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/css/ymobiz.css",
            "~/Content/css/Style.css",
            "~/Content/css/datepicker3.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",
            "~/Content/css/css.css"
            ));


        //To enable bundling and minification
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

Now i need to enable caching for these files as well. Is there any way by which we can control caching duration for these bundles files

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC bundle client caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374656/mvc-bundle-client-caching)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MVC bundles are returned as a single static file to browsers whose cache time is set to 1 year by default. ASP.NET MVC takes care of change tracking of your bundle files and changes bundle url if content of any file is changed or a file is being added / removed from bundle.

As bundles are already cached and change tracking is maintained by asp.net mvc framework, what else cache control do you want on those bundles?

**EDIT** (in response to comment)

Unfortunately you can not alter that limit. Cache limit is handles by `ProcessRequest` method of `BundleHandler` class and this is `internal sealed` so there is no chance that you can inherit \ override these requests.

For further details you can [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374656/mvc-bundle-client-caching).

Comment: see stackoverflow.com/a/34508048/1545567 to control the cache duration

Answer (score 0):

Add a key in webconfig

```
<appSettings>  
<add key="Version" value="sa291988" />  
</appSettings>
```

Create a class, where we define the format for both JavaScript and styles.
using System.Configuration;

```
namespace BundlingSample   
{  
public class SiteKeys {  
    public static string StyleVersion {  
        get {  
            return "<link href=\"{0}?v=" + 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"] + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>";  
        }  
    }  
    public static string ScriptVersion {  
        get {  
            return "<script src=\"{0}?v=" + 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"] + "\"></script>";  
        }  
    }  
}  
}
```

---

```
@Styles.RenderFormat(SiteKeys.StyleVersion,"~/Content/css") 
@Scripts.RenderFormat(SiteKeys.ScriptVersion,"~/bundles/jquery")
```